# PHP mktime() for dates pre 1900

Tags: php, datetime, mktime

So I am working on this system that is sorting dates by decades. I am using make times and I have everything working fine until it hits the year 1900 or below. Afer that everything returns a Dec 24,1964 type date. Can anyone else me why this is happening and a possbile soltuion?

And the code for this:

```
//$decades is a string ex: '1950-1960'

$decade_array=explode('-',$decades);

$date_active=date("M-d-Y", mktime(0, 0, 0, 1,1 , trim($decade_array[0]) ));
$date_inactive=date("M-d-Y", mktime(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, trim($decade_array[1]) ));

echo $date_active.' '.$date_inactive;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

alternative procedural function

```
date_format(date_create('1234-01-01'), 'M-d-Y');
```

Comment: ([`date_create(...)`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php) is an alias for [`new DateTime(...)`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php) and returns a `DateTime` object, both are available since PHP 5.2. `date_format` is an alias for `DateTime->format()` and takes a `DateTime` object as parameter.)

Answer (score 7):

Try with the [`DateTime`](http://php.net/DateTime) class:

```
$date = new DateTime("1234-01-01");
echo $date->format("M-d-Y"); // outputs Jan-01-1234
```

The DateTime class is available since PHP 5.2.

If you have PHP 5.3, use [`DateTime::createFromFormat`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php):

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', "1234-01-01");
echo $date->format("M-d-Y");
```